# How to return partial types with Apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

In my app I have alerts. Partial schema:

```
type Alert {
  id: ID!
  users: [User]
}

type User {
  id
  username
  ... many more calculated fields
}
```

Each alert can return a list of `User`s. This `User` type is computationally expensive to build and we really only need a couple of user fields to display on an alert. However, if we only partially build the user object, Apollo will cache these partial user objects and break other parts of the app that depend on "complete" `User` objects. Avoiding this would require `fetchPolicy: "no-cache"`, and I'd like to retain that caching.

So I'm trying to avoid returning entire `User` objects just to support an `Alert`. I've run into this issue with other types as well and am struggling with the best way to architect for this. The only solution I've come up with is to create "partial types", which would be separate types with a subset of fields. For example:

```
type Alert {
  id: ID!
  users: [PartialUser]
}    

type PartialUser {
  id
  username
  name
}
```

This feels hacky and like it violates DRY principles.

Another way might be to manually update the cache after a query. This would avoid the caching of partial `User` objects, but still feels hacky. I also think that only mutations support the `options.update` method to manipulate the cache. So I'm a bit stuck and haven't found any guidance in the docs.

Are there any recommendations for approaching this problem?

Comment: If you're seeing a cache hit on partial results, there may be something else going on. I believe the default behavior should be a cache miss in those scenarios. There's a [PR that was just merged](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/4743) to opt in to receiving partial results instead with a full explanation in the comments.

Comment: If I return a partial User, it will overwrite the user in the cache with the new data while setting any missing fields to null. So if I only return an id for user, the user object in cache will have an id and nulls for everything else. I would expect it to merge instead of replace but could be confused. Looks like the update you mention will be a part of 2.6.0. Will try it out, thanks.

Comment: Merging is the expected behavior in that scenario, unless something has changed with a newer version :/